# debian wireless networking configuration

Tags: debian, networking, wifi

When I issue the command

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid NAME
```

it sometimes takes a really long time to actually be able to view any webpages through a browser. I don't know why that is. Right now the /etc/network/interfaces file contains the following:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    # wireless-* options are implemented by the wireless-tools package
    wireless-mode managed
    wireless-essid NAME2
```

when I boot, there's never any issue like this. I never have to wait. So I tried changing NAME2 to NAME and the same problem remained. What can I do about this?

What I really want is for debian to *just* connect automatically to either NAME or NAME2 or any open wireless connection. I'm not sure whether this requires configuration in /etc/network/interfaces or /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf. I'm currently trying to find examples of how to configure the files. So my questions are

1. how do I make the appropriate configuration?
2. do I even need the network-manager to do this?

Comment: My guess would be that the DHCP takes a while... how long exactly is "a really long time"?

Comment: More than 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

See my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40477/16973) for details on how to configure multiple wireless networks. The delay you're seeing is DHCP, because there's no mechanism to trigger the DHCP client when the wireless connection is actually established. You probably just need to do `ifdown wlan0` and `ifup wlan0` when you want to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/etc/init.d/networking force-reload
```

This command reboot the network service when you changed any parameter of the current configuration.

Later the changes on the interface configuration can be applied whitout any waiting time.